# Implementing an ever changing color system in pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

At this moment I have a game that drops falling colored blocks (*obstacles*) from the top of the screen, and the objective is for the player to dodge said (*obstacles*) by moving either left or right.

I currently have set up where every time the user runs the script, the blocks will be a different color, but the problem is, they will **only** be that color for the duration of game play, and for the color to be different, the user would have to exit and re-run the script.

The code I have for this:

```
col1 = randint(1, 255)
col2 = randint(1, 255)
col3 = randint(1, 255)
block_color = (col1, col2, col3)
```

Once the script is executed, a random color is defined by the three randints above, and its applied later in the script.

I'm looking for advice on how I might be able to change the color of **every single block that falls**.

So, for example, one block falls and it's randcolor is red, and then the second block falls and it's randcolor is blue, etc.

I imagine it would function along the lines of defining 3 random integers every time a block falls and applying those three rgb values to the new block. I just cannot figure how to actually write that in python.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You probably just need to call the random function for every new block that's created but without seeing your code, I don't know where that might be. "Place it within the game loop somewhere" is the best I can do at the moment.

Comment: Make a list or dictionary where every entry contains three RGB values that represent the colours you want (or use completely random colours and risk having colours that might match the background and things like that). You then cycle this list or dictionary every time a block is created or use `random.choice()` to pick a random colour for the block every time a new one is created. But still, we need to see some code to give you more than pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish this is by having a Block class, and making the color in the **init** method, so that every Block object (your obstacle) will have a different color.

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self):
        col1 = randint(1, 255)
        col2 = randint(1, 255)
        col3 = randint(1, 255)
        self.block_color = (col1, col2, col3)
```

Note that it is important to put the randint INSIDE the init method, or the random will be called one time and used for the whole game. This way, it's different for each block.

If you get all of your image/rect stuff inside of a Block class, your code for the block will become very simple.

```
b1 = Block() # Makes a block object.
b1.block_color # Will access b1's unique color.
```

Note: if you don't use a class, the comments on your question could solve the problem. However, you generally want classes for things that have unique properties (especially in video games), such as your falling obstacle.

Comment: @David Jay Brady  This helps so much, thank you very much! 
Although I understand the concept you are presenting, I still don't understand how to actually implement the class into my code.

Is there a way I could share what I have with you, and you could take a look at the whole thing to better help me?

Comment: @marienbad I'm sorry about that. The reason I still answered the question was I felt the person asking could use some more explanation, as he wouldn't have asked the question if he had more experience.

Comment: Sure thing @FourTwenty, send me a pastebin link. I'll give you some pointers, although I won't write much as I'm pretty busy.

Comment: https://ghostbin.com/paste/xvnhs

@DavidJayBrady I have to use ghostbin because i'm at school, sorry for that haha.

Comment: @DavidJayBrady also I apologize for the lack of documentation and sloppiness, I've only just started learning pygame. Any ideas you have for me I would greatly appreciate!

Comment: I'll work with, improve, and leave comments in your code and leave you a pastebin link soon. That should put you in the right direction =)

Comment: I really cannot thank you enough... Is there any way I can give you extra rep or something else beneficial to you? You answered my question and then some, and I am extremely grateful for that! @DavidJayBrady

Comment: Umm I could think of one, but don't bother. I don't care for that number much (I did at first). I'm just happy I could help =D Your thank you is enough

Answer (score 0):

```
class block
    def __init__(self):
     (put the colour code here)
     self.colour = (col1, col2, col3)
```

Sorry for formatting, am on tablet while at work.